# Why does one of these font-face render in IE8, but the others don't?

Tags: css, internet-explorer, fonts, font-face

Why does this fontface render in IE8:

```
@font-face {
  font-family: 'Aller';
  src: url('aller_rg-webfont.eot');
  src: url('aller_rg-webfont.eot?#iefix') format('embedded-opentype'),
       url('aller_rg-webfont.woff') format('woff'),
       url('aller_rg-webfont.ttf') format('truetype'),
       url('aller_rg-webfont.svg#AllerRegular') format('svg');
  font-weight: normal;
  font-style: normal;
}
```

And this does not:

```
@font-face {
  font-family: 'Champagne';
  src: url('champreg-webfont.eot');
  src: url('champreg-webfont.eot?#iefix') format('embedded-opentype'),
       url('champreg-webfont.woff') format('woff'),
       url('champreg-webfont.ttf') format('truetype'),
       url('champreg-webfont.svg#Champagne&LimousinesRegular') format('svg');
  font-weight: normal;
  font-style: normal;
}
```

I really can't figure it out. All other browsers work fine, obviously.

Answer (score 32, accepted):

Try creating a new `.eot` file with one of the others using an online woff/ttf/svg to eot convertor.

- http://www.font2web.com/
- http://www.fontsquirrel.com/fontface/generator <- might have problems because they black list font names.

If this new file doesn't work, then it might be a problem with the font itself. Sometimes IE6-8 has a fit if the Fontname and Family Name are not the same within the actual font file.  To fix it:

- You'll need to download [FontForge](http://sourceforge.net/projects/fontforge/)
- Open up the font
- From the menu, choose `Element` > `Font Info`
- Ensure the Fontname, Family Name and Name for Humans are **all the same**
- Save the font as a TTF or OTF and use an online convertor to spit out an EOT file.

Every issue I've had with font-face - if the CSS was correct - worked with one of the above two solutions, so good luck :-) Maybe even try saving the font without any changes in FontForge and converting that online before you fiddle with the name properties.

Comment: Wow...renaming the font info via FontForge actually worked! Learnt something today, thank you Patrick

Comment: This not only solved my IE9 problem (it was working, but logging an error in the console), but it also got it working for IE8. A hug thanks!

Comment: I also ran into this very same problem, I compiled the fixed EOT file and shared it here: http://gist.github.com/vjt/7436066. I hope this saves someone the very bad time I spent fighting with FontForge on Windows.

Comment: This solved my problem, but some eot files fixed by next case:
Edit .otf file in FontForge: set all the same in  **PS Names** and **TTF Names**
`Element - Font info... - PS Names : Fontname, Family Name, Name For Humans
Element - Font info... - TTF Names : Family.`
Generate ttf file with modifications and convert ttf to eot by [ttf2eot converter](https://github.com/metaflop/ttf2eot/)

Answer (score 0):

1. Added this to htaccess. "BrowserMatch MSIE best-standards-support Header set X-UA-Compatible IE=8 env=best-standards-support"
2. trying to reconvert eot font
3. doc compactibility mode chnage
4. tried usleep function
5. setInterval js
6. add google html5 script
7. call css in body part for ie8
8. add data-icon class
9. ad pseudo elements js
10. add png & svg filters in css
11. check font type Permission in server

but finally works when added

> **.sass and .less css**

files 
happy coding...
by
sivakumar

Answer (score 0):

Under IIS (MVC environment) I had to add the following rule to my Web.config:

```
   <system.web>
    <httpHandlers>
      <add verb="GET" path="*.eot" type="System.Web.StaticFileHandler" />
      <add verb="GET" path="*.svg" type="System.Web.StaticFileHandler" />
      <add verb="GET" path="*.ttf" type="System.Web.StaticFileHandler" />
      <add verb="GET" path="*.woff" type="System.Web.StaticFileHandler" />
      <add verb="GET" path="*.otf" type="System.Web.StaticFileHandler" />
    </httpHandlers>
  </system.web>
```