# two @font-face not acting like each other

Tags: html, css, wordpress, fonts, font-face

I'm using two @font-face in CSSreset.css exactly like each other, and just one of them works!
This is the style code:

```
@font-face {
        font-family: 'B Mitra';
        src: url('./fonts/B Mitra.eot');
        src: url('./fonts/B Mitra.eot?#iefix') format('embedded-opentype'),
        url('./fonts/B Mitra.woff') format('woff'),
        url('./fonts/B Mitra.ttf') format('truetype'),
        url('./fonts/B Mitra.svg#webfont') format('svg');
    }

@font-face {
        font-family: 'BBCNassim';
        src: url('./fonts/BBCNassim.eot');
        src: url('./fonts/BBCNassim.eot?#iefix') format('embedded-opentype'),
        url('./fonts/BBCNassim.woff') format('woff'),
        url('./fonts/BBCNassim.ttf') format('truetype'),
        url('./fonts/BBCNassim.svg#webfont') format('svg');
    }
```

The second @font-face not working well. this is how I use them in my stylesheet:

```
#Download > a {
        font-family: 'BBCNassim';
    }
```

This is not working and shows "tahoma" font. the wierd part is, if the "BBCNassim" font not load correctly, the default browser font shows.
So, when I use `font-family: 'BBCNassim';`, the font will be tahoma.

This is the "B Mitra" font witch shows and load correctly:

```
#Map_Eshterak {
        font-family: 'B Mitra';
    }
```

SCREENSHOT: https://i.stack.imgur.com/ptIz5.jpg

The problem is not from the font; because if i copy "B Mitra" fonts, and change the name to "BBC Nassim", the same thing will happen.

- this is my directory : https://i.stack.imgur.com/WbYtI.png

Comment: In which browser are you seeing this problem. Can you please create a fiddle.

Comment: Is the BBCNassim font being requested and sent by the server? You can check in the networks tab. Also, can we see the markup around the link you are trying add the BBCNassim font to?

Comment: The screenshot isn't acessible from outside. And can you show the HTML where the fonts are supposed to be used? By the way, are you saying the url with the space in it works flawlessly and the other doesn't? Hm, funny.

Comment: @jfelsinger yep. both of them. http://i.imgur.com/ufBWuIo.png

Comment: @MrLister Sorry. Screenshot replaced. and this is the HTML: `<li id="Download">
                    <a href="#">دانلود کنید!<span id="Download_Logo"></span></a>
                </li>` . and I dont understood the space thing :)

Comment: OK guys. I realized that Firefox and IE works fine and Show both fonts correctly. mybe the problem is because i'm using google chrome 32.0.1700.68 BETA. i'm going to download stable version and let you know.

Comment: I must say that the Chrome betas are always very stable for me. Currently using the v34 Canary without problems.

Comment: @MrLister Yes. I never had problem with unstable chrome too. but i think its the only option.

Comment: NO LUCK. stable chrome not working too!

Answer (score 0):

Could it be the CSS selectors you're using? Does it work if you change your code to:

```
#Map_Eshterak {
        font-family: 'BBCNassim';
}
```

And as a side-note, once you get this working you may want to give a font stack, in case your @font-face fonts don't load properly. (For example, `font-family: 'BBCNassim', Helvetica, sans-serif;` will show Helvetica is BBCNassim isn't available)

Comment: Hm, strange. I'd guess then that it's a problem with the font file. Are you able to re-save out the fonts? The accepted answer to [this question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12449512/why-does-one-of-these-font-face-render-in-ie8-but-the-others-dont?rq=1) may help you out.